# Consume WCF Data Services (OData) from .NET with untyped objects

Tags: .net, wcf, dynamic, odata, strong-typing

I have a requirement for a ASP.NET web application to submit leads into a crm system through OData.

The only API to consume OData in .Net, aside from using the HTTP level, seems to be the `DataServiceContext` class, and calling its generic `CreateQuery<>` method, e.g. `CreateQuery<Lead>("LeadSet");` this however would require my code to have strong typed classes that match the OData entities.

My problem with this approach is that, for various reasons, I don't want to use static typing.

Is there any way to use the DataServiceContext with untyped objects? Or is there another OData client library that I don't know about?

My goal is to be able to write something like this:

```
var lead = new Entity("Lead");
lead["name"] = "Larry Jones";
lead["source"] = "google";
lead["email"] = "test@test.com";
context.AddObject("LeadSet", lead);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Perhaps with dynamic this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

We're currently working on this, so called ODataLib. The first CTP of it is part of the WCF Data Services CTP1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-wcf-data-services-june-2011-ctp-for-net4-amp-sl4.aspx.
Although that version can only read JSON and only if you do have metadata, so it's very likely not usable for you yet. We're working on ATOM reading and easier metadata story as well.
There's also a source version, although that one is a bit older drop: http://odata.codeplex.com/releases/view/60787

Comment: Has this situation changed? Is there now a way to consume WCF Data Services with untyped objects? - Thanks

Comment: The ODataLib has been released (a while back) - it's for example on NuGet as Microsoft.Data.OData.dll. It supports all of OData (the WCF Data Services uses it internally for all reading/writing).